# How to iterate over list for Twilio SMS?

Tags: python, sms, twilio

I am working on a python application for Twilio. I need to send my SMS to mulitple numbers.

As a test I put two numbers into a list to iterate over. The issue I am having is that in my iteration is only looking the first number and not going to the next one. I discovered this by setting a pause of 10seconds and got the same text twice on my number.

What I am doing wrong that the iteration is not iterating the next value in the list?

Code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import time

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "xxxx"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "xxxx"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


lst = ["+11111111111","+22222222222"]

for i in lst:
    message = client.messages.create(
            to=lst, 
            from_="+1234567890",
            body="Hello from Python!")
    time.sleep(10)
    print(message.sid)
```

Comment: Try replacing `to=lst` with `to=i`?

Comment: @Xay thank you so much that works!

Comment: Feel free to leave an answer so I can accept it for you.

Comment: @RustyShakleford No problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `to=lst` with `to=i` in the for-loop when creating the message object, like this

```
for i in lst:
    message = client.messages.create(
            to=i, 
            from_="+1234567890",
            body="Hello from Python!")
    time.sleep(10)
    print(message.sid)
```